# Is there a way to make the polkit agent default to the currently logged in user?

Tags: linux, gnome, authentication

Does anyone know how to configure polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 to default to the current user initially when handling a request, or alternatively if one of the other polkit agents has this ability?

---

When authenticating to perform a polkit action with an agent like `polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`, because I have multiple users in the `wheel` group I'm provided a drop down to select which user to authenticate as.

This is an irritating extra step, when in most cases the user I want to authenticate as, is the currently logged in user*. My preferred behaviour is that the currently logged in user is pre-selected and I'm taken straight to password entry, with the option to change to another user if that's what I want.

I'm aware that it's possible to restrict the users that appear in the list via polkit rules but my naive understanding of those rules is they change who is **allowed** to authenticate for certain actions, and that this behaviour is instead in the realm of the polkit GUI agent. Or am I wrong and that the default selection is something that can be set via polkit rules?

To reiterate **I don't wish to change which users/groups are allowed to authenticate to perform polkit actions but just make the UI a little quicker to move through with minimum keypresses and definitely no rodents.**

<sub>* I fully acknowledge that this might be the most sensible behaviour for most deployments, but for me its awkward.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The way I managed to solve this issue is by adding a custom file to `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/` named `00-custom.rules` with the following lines, to override the `50-default.rules`:

```
polkit.addAdminRule(function(action, subject) {
    if( subject.isInGroup("wheel") ) {
        return ["unix-user:"+subject.user];
    }
    else {
        return [polkit.Result.NO];
    }
});
```

This way the current user, if present in the `wheel` group, will be prompted for their password, otherwise for the root password.